# SQL DELETE WITH JOIN not working

Tags: sql, select

I have this query, which returns all records from Keywords which does not have a Quote
The query is working, but I want to DELETE all these records, the problem is that if I put DELETE instead of SELECT I get errors.

```
SELECT Keywords.[Id]
  ,[QuoteId]      
  FROM [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords]
 LEFT JOIN [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Quotes ON Keywords.QuoteId=Quotes.Id
  WHERE Quotes.Id IS NULL
```

This does not work.

```
DELETE
  FROM [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords]
  LEFT JOIN [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Quotes ON Keywords.QuoteId=Quotes.Id
  WHERE Quotes.Id IS NULL
```

I get this error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
DELETE [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords] FROM [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords]
  LEFT JOIN [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Quotes ON Keywords.QuoteId=Quotes.Id
  WHERE Quotes.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Valid syntax is:

```
DELETE [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords]
FROM [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Keywords] AS k
LEFT JOIN [QuotesTemple].[dbo].[Quotes] AS q ON k.QuoteId = q.Id
WHERE q.Id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
you can also write as below

delete t1 FROM projects AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Quotes AS t2 on t1.QuoteId= t2.QuoteId where t2.Id is Null
```